# Cannot assign to read only property 'x' of true

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm running into a frustrating issue in my Angular controller. I'm trying to conditionally set the values of certain fields of objects I attach to my scope. The `if` block below works perfectly by itself, but as soon as I add the `else` block I run into the following error:

`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'gameType' of true`

```
var getGames = function() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  playersService.getGames({
    playerId: playerId
  }).$promise.then(function(data) {
    vm.games = data;

    for (var x in vm.games) {
      if (vm.games[x].activity_type === 'preseason') {
        vm.games[x].gameType = 'preseason';
      } else {
        vm.games[x].gameType = vm.games[x].type;
      }
    }
    defer.resolve(data);
  });
  return defer.promise;
};
```

After `console.log`'ing `vm.games[x]` within the `else` block I'm seeing the error occurs when I hit:

```
Promise {$$state: Object}
true
```

...whereas all the other lines show:

```
Resource {id: "...", ...}
```

Comment: I'd `console.log` the value of `vm.games` and `vm.games[x]` and see what they are inside the else. My guess is it's not what you think it is when the else is being hit.

Comment: or `console.table()` if there's an array of similar objects

Comment: @tymeJV, edited question to be more detailed.

Comment: I'd guess, `vm.games[x].gameType` was defined with `Object.defineProperty()` (or `Object.defineProperties()`, or in `Object.createObject()`) and has `writable` set to `false`.

Comment: @MattDionis -- Can you post the actual data structure of `vm.games`

Comment: @tymeJV, @Teemu, @dman2306, @iam-decoder Added details after logging `vm.games[x]`.

Comment: Can you `console.log(data)` before you do any logic - and post that? It'd help to see the structure of the data you're iterating.

Comment: @tymeJV, I honestly can't. This is a sensitive project and I've already heavily changed the wording to obscure the actual project.

Comment: Ahh, damn. Well, is `vm.games` an Array or an Object?

Comment: @tymeJV, it is an array of objects.

Comment: Don't use a `for in` loop on array, use a standard `for` loop. `for in` is for iterating the properties of an object.

Comment: The error message actually tells, that `vm.games[x].gameType` is a boolean, and the said property is write-protected in `Object.defineProperties` or similar method.

Comment: Bingo @tymeJV! Boneheaded mistake on my part. If you post that as an answer I'd like to credit you.

Comment: Hah, always happy to help - glad it was something easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `for in` loop on array, use a standard `for` loop. `for in` is for iterating the properties of an object. This could be causing some hiccups when assigning property values.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vm.games[x].gameType` data type and `vm.games[x].type;` data type may different.

if your if condition worked perfectly then you can try

```
      if (vm.games[x].activity_type === 'preseason') {
        vm.games[x].gameType = 'preseason';
      } else {
        vm.games[x].gameType = ''+ vm.games[x].type; // ''+ is convert to string
      }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't solve it. I've added details to my question after logging `vm.games[x]`.